# JSON Schema to Java Classes for FHIR

Tags: java, json, spring, hl7-fhir

I am trying to Implement FHIR HL7 in my project, Downloaded JSON Schemas ( http://hl7.org/fhir/downloads.html ) and now I want to generate java classes from the schema, How can I do it? any links/sample codes are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're far better off using the existing HAPI reference implementation which is generated from the resources and supports both XML & Java, handles terminology and many other things that classes generated from the JSON schemas can't do.

Comment: I am struggling with mapping, where a parameter is Type and want to set String or Param is a reference and want to set Patient object. Any Example or sample?

Comment: You can't send a Patient (or any other resource) when the type is Reference - you can only specify a URL that points to it.  In some cases, the reference might point to a "contained" resource - in situations where the referenced resource can't stand on its own.  In other cases it will point to an external resource sitting on a server or, in the case of a Message, Document or other Bundle, it'll refer to a resource within the Bundle.

Comment: is there any way where I can just pass the java object? do you have any link for sample/demo project of FHIR HL7 implementation?

Comment: I already implemented ncpdp standard, I just want to map to FHIR HL 7 standard. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to be conformant, you need to send one of the defined syntaxes - XML, JSON or RDF.  The HAPI implementation produces those, so it shouldn't be an issue.  There's a reference implementation here: https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir.  We provide mappings to NCPDP for several resource.  E.g. http://build.fhir.org/medicationrequest-mappings.html#script10.6

Comment: If I have one Drug, that is Theraflue, quantity is 10, strength is 50mg. How will you set this value?could you please give some snippet

Comment: Can I put whole patient details inside medicationdispense and medicationdispense Inside messageheader in json?

Comment: Doing so would be incorrect.  If you're sending a FHIR Message (which is the only reason to have a MessageHeader) you MUST wrap everything in a FHIR Bundle.  Each resource - the MessageHeader, the MedicationDispense, the Patient (and quite possibly the Medication and various Practitioner, Organization and other resources) should all be separate entries in the Bundle.  While it's possible to nest one resource inside another using the 'contained' element, that's intended only for resources that can't stand alone.

Comment: Is quantity the dispense quantity (dispense 10 tablets) or the dose quantity (take 10 tablets)?  The answer will vary accordingly.  The strength can be conveyed a few ways.  Sometimes it's just included as part of the drug code.  Alternatively, you can express it as a quantity of an ingredient.  (Drugs can have multiple active ingredients - e.g. Tylenol 3, so strength is expressed on a per-ingredient basis.)

Comment: What’s the parent class if I want to use fhir bundle?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "parent class".  Bundle is a resource like any other - it's just a resource that can contain other resources.

Comment: What would be the return type if I want to use Bundle for including patient, dispenser, prescriptions in one json?